# Can't remove total line from Pivot Chart

Tags: excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I've unchecked the totals on the Pivot Table options, but it seems to be incorrectly using the Grand Total value for the course with ID ending `6472` (total value = 230).

How do I fix this?

[image: Excel Pivot Table gone haywire]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the "Course" legend is filtered. Also, the blue line for total 230 is not just for the last record number 100. It is total for each record. Hence, it is always on top of all other lines.

This indicates that the source data is having an additional course which is filtered out. Remove the filter then you will see actual 6472 course is repeated in the source data as many times as the total of all other courses. This may be a mistake while labeling the total of mails for each records (from 1 to 100) in the source data.

If there is no such problem with the source data, the pivot and chart should look something like this. (without the top blue line for total and irrespective of the totals in the table.
[image]

Comment: Oh! .. That makes sense .. I missed that :) Thanks

Comment: Thank YOU - you got me checking & re-checking my data, led me to the problem...